# Is is possible to use javascript to mix 2 SVG files in one resulting an HTML/HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm creating a software that uses an embedded browser to show SVG files (HTML/HTML5 with SVG).

A lot of SVG files would have a lot in common, so I'd like to avoid copying that part to all SVG files. I'd like to provide a base SVG to be extended/included. Lets call the base SVG "base.svg".

I searched for something like INCLUDE in SVG but it doesn't exist.

Is it possible to create a HTML file that has an HTML5 link element, or javascript code to include the base.svg?
Then I'd simply put the rest of SVG in the HTML. Something like this (pseudo):

```
<html>
<body>
    <link rel="import" href="base.svg" />
    <!-- or some javascript code to include the base.svg content -->

    <svg>
        <!-- The rest of the SVG -->
    </svg>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible?
If not, is it a good choice to use a PHP server (or something like this) to generate the complete SVG dynamically (result = base.svg + rest.svg)?

Thanks very much.

=== Solution (based on Francis Hemsher approach):

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Combine/Parse SVG Files via XML DOM</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='padding:0px;font-family:arial'>
    <center>
        <h4>Combine/Parse SVG Files via XML DOM</h4>
        <div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
            Load svg files as XML via <b>XMLHttpRequest</b>. Parse the Document Elements to create a client's file.
            This example first loads the <b>Base.svg</b> inline into a DIV, then extracts/adds elements from another <b>companion</b> svg file,
            combining them into a seamless svg root.
        </div>
        <br />
        Base + Companion SVG:
        <textarea id=svgValue style='width:90%;height:100px;font-size:120%;font-family:lucida console;'></textarea>
        <div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:white;width:400px;height:400px;' ></div>
        <br />
        Parameters:
        <br />
        <textarea id=jsParams style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:40px'></textarea>
        <br />
        Javascript:
        <br />
        <textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
    </center>

<script id="parameterRetrieval">
    var params = new Array();

    function queryParameters() {
        var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
        var lParams = query.split('&');
        for (var i = 0; i < lParams.length; ++i) {
            var pos = lParams[i].indexOf('=');
            if (pos > 0) {
                var key = lParams[i].substring(0, pos);
                var val = lParams[i].substring(pos + 1);
                params[key] = val;
                console.log("params[ " + key + " ] = \"" + val + "\"");
            }
        }
    }

    function getParameterByName(key) {
        return params[key];
    }
</script>

<script id="SVGComposer">   
    var  XMLdoc;

    function loadCompanionXML() {
        // Element inside the base SVG file to hold the companion SVG content.
        var destElement = getParameterByName("destination");
        // Companion SVG name.
        var SVGFile = getParameterByName("svg");
        if (SVGFile == null) {
            console.log("Missing parameter: child svg file (svg).");
            return;
        }
        var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
        function handler() {
            if ((loadXML.readyState == 4) && (loadXML.status == 200)) {
                var childSVG = document.getElementById(destElement);
                if (childSVG != null) {
                    childSVG.innerHTML = loadXML.responseText;
                    svgValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML;
                } else {
                    console.log("Could not get the child SVG container.");
                }
            }
        }
        if (loadXML != null) {
            loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
            loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
            loadXML.send();
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener("onload", init(), false);
    function init() {
        queryParameters();

        var SVGFile = "base.svg";
        var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
        function handler() {
            if ((loadXML.readyState == 4) && (loadXML.status == 200)) {
                svgDiv.innerHTML = loadXML.responseText;
                loadCompanionXML();
            }
        }
        if (loadXML != null) {
            loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
            loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
            loadXML.send();
        }

        jsValue.value = SVGComposer.text;
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

base.svg:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="w3.org/1999/xlink" id="baseSVG" width="400" height="400" fill="white">
    <circle r="50" fill="green" cx="50" cy="50" stroke="none" />
    <g id="childSVG" />
</svg>
```

companion.svg:

```
<defs>
    <image id="bkimage" xlink:href="http://placepuppy.it/320/240" width="100%" height="100%" />
    <rect id="MyRect" width="100" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" />
</defs>

<g>
    <defs>
        <mask id="image1mask" ><polygon points="0,0, 320,0, 160,120, 320,240, 0,240" fill-opacity="30%" /></mask>
    </defs>
<use xlink:href="#bkimage" mask="url(#image1mask)"/>
</g>
<use xlink:href="#MyRect" x="100" y="100" fill="red" />
<use xlink:href="#MyRect" x="150" y="150" fill="blue" />
<use xlink:href="#MyRect" x="200" y="200" fill="green" />
<g>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="MyRectClip"><rect x="270" y="270" width="60" height="60" /></clipPath>
    </defs>
    <rect x="250" y="250" width="100" height="100" stroke="black" stroke-width="2" fill="yellow" clip-path="url(#MyRectClip)"/>
</g>
```

To load it, you should open the following URL:

```
http://theHTMLfile?svg=companion.svg&destination=childSVG
```

Ps: I know the coordinates of the image mask are not working very well. Ignore that. It was just a test.
Cheers!

Comment: Can't you just overlay the SVGs?

Comment: include in SVG is accomplished by the `<use>` element. Does that cover what you need? If not can you clarify what you are looking for?

Comment: As far as I know, the <use> element cant reference another file. Am I wrong?

Comment: I want to use something like a C/C++ include directive. I have a huge SVG definition file, and a lot of small SVG files that use those definitions. I don't want to have a lot of big SVG files that have a huge common part between them (it is hard to maintain).

Comment: You are wrong, `<use>` can reference another file. Chrome doesn't implement that yet though I think though Firefox does.

Comment: That's the biggest problem. The browser I have to use (embedded browser from JavaFX2) can't do that either.

Comment: @jtromans: How can I overlay the SVGs? Is it possible to have a <defs> in the first one and use those defined elements in the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have access to the XML DOM. If so, the best way to merge the svg is via xml dom methods.

```
EDIT (added below) UPDATE: added xlink namespace, needed for image elements
```

Below is a very basic means of combining svg files into a single inline svg on the client. It it can Combine/Parse SVG Files via XML DOM.

Loads svg files as XML via `XMLHttpRequest`. Parse the Document Elements to create a client's file.
This example first loads the **Base.svg** inline into a DIV, then extracts/adds elements from another **companion.svg** file,
combining them into a seamless svg root.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <title>Combine/Parse SVG Files via XML DOM</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body style='padding:0px;font-family:arial'>
    <center><h4>Combine/Parse SVG Files via XML DOM</h4>
    <div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
    Load svg files as XML via <b>XMLHttpRequest</b>. Parse the Document Elements to create a client's file.
    This example first loads the <b>Base.svg</b> inline into a DIV, then extracts/adds elements from another <b>companion</b> svg file,
    combining them into a seamless svg root.
    </div>
    <br />Base + Companion SVG:
    <textarea id=svgValue style='width:90%;height:200px;font-size:120%;font-family:lucida console;'></textarea>
    <div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;' ></div>
    <br />Javascript:<br />
    <textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:400px'></textarea>
    </center>

    <script id=myScript>
    /*


Base.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  id="baseSVG" width="400" height="400">
<circle r="50" fill="green" cx="100" cy="100" stroke="none" />
</svg>

companion.svg
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  id="companionSVG">
<rect x="180" y="200" width="200" height="150" fill="red" />
<ellipse cx="70" cy="300" rx="65" ry="25" fill="blue" />
<image x="120" y="100"  xlink:href="myImage.png" width="198" height="65" />
</svg>

    */
    //--onload---
    function loadBaseSVGInline()
    {
        var SVGFile="Base.svg"
        var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
        function handler(){
            if(loadXML.readyState == 4 && loadXML.status == 200)
            {
                svgDiv.innerHTML=loadXML.responseText
                loadCompanionXML()
            }
        }
        if (loadXML != null){
            loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
            loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
            loadXML.send();
        }
    }
    var  XMLdoc
    function loadCompanionXML()
    {
        var SVGFile="companion.svg"
        var loadXML = new XMLHttpRequest;
        function handler()
        {
            if(loadXML.readyState == 4 && loadXML.status == 200)
            {
                //---responseText---
                var xmlString=loadXML.responseText
                //---DOMParser---
                var parser = new DOMParser();
                XMLdoc=parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml").documentElement;
                companionXML2Base()
            }
        }
        if (loadXML != null){
            loadXML.open("GET", SVGFile, true);
            loadXML.onreadystatechange = handler;
            loadXML.send();
        }
    }
    //--place companion elements into base
    function companionXML2Base()
    {
        var mySVG=document.getElementsByTagName("svg")[0]
        var elems=XMLdoc.childNodes
        for(var k=0;k<elems.length;k++)
        {
            var elem=elems.item(k).cloneNode(true)
            mySVG.appendChild(elem)
        }

        svgValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML

    }
    </script>
    <script>
    document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
    function init()
    {
        loadBaseSVGInline()
        jsValue.value=myScript.text
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Ok, but how? Should I create an internal tag to the SVG tag and populate that with with DEFS from the base.svg file? Are you sure it is going to work? Is the SVG going to understand the missing references after I load them using dom methods?

Comment: Let me see if I can give an example to start with...sorry I didn't do that originally, but I'm on the move at present.

Comment: Don't worry. I really appreaciate your answer. Sorry if I sounded unthankful.

Comment: I made a few tests. Using JS, I created a new element, set its type to "image/svg+xml" and set its data property to the svg file I wanted to load. It didn't work (file wasn't actually loaded). I'm trying to get something here.

Comment: You are my hero! Your example was beyond any expectations. Thanks so much. I suppose you spent some time to do that. I really appreciate. Thanks again.

Comment: The only thing to notice is that it is not processing all the tags from the companion SVG. I'm trying to understand why.

Comment: Actually, the problem is with SVG image tags. Looks like it fails to resolve the image link. Do you know how to deal with that?

Comment: I think that the namespace xlink:href may need to be included...I try a test and see what happens.

Comment: Your image must have xlink:href="imagefile", and both the base and companion must include  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" in their root svg. Give that a try

Comment: You are right. It loaded the entire SVG now. But images are not rendered. I believe it is not possible to do it on client side. Did you manage to load and show images?

Comment: I found a way to do it. Instead of parsing the companion SVG with a DOM parser, I did something similar to what you did when requesting the base SVG: I used getElementById to find an empty group inside the base SVG ("<g id='changeMe' />") and used changeMe.innerHTML = loadXML.responseText; It worked fine. Do you think it is a bad solution?

Comment: Thanks so much Francis. You did it.

Comment: I think you have the right idea, and understand how this method can be adjusted to fit your needs. Good luck, Marcus